# Подскажите редактор наподобие Notepad++ для Ubuntu с поддержкой FTP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp

Подскажите похожий на Notepad++ редактор с обязательной поддержкой FTP

Comment: `Wine` + `Notepad++`. Да, я извращенец, а что?

Comment: sublime например

Answer (score 3, accepted):

иногда разумным бывает подход «используем набор специализированных инструментов вместо одного монстрообразного».

в применении к данному случаю задачу можно разделить на две:

1. монтирование файловой системы
2. работа с файлами как с локальными

реализация:

1. для монтирования файловой системы по протоколу *ftp* можно воспользоваться, например, программой *curlftpfs* из одноименного пакета:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install curlftpfs
   ```

   1. как обычно в случае *fuse* ([file system in userspace](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace)), лучше создать для последующего использования отдельный пустой каталог:

      ```
      $ mkdir ~/pustoi.katalog
      ```
   2. и монтировать туда файловую систему:

      ```
      $ curlftpfs ftp://пользователь:пароль@хост ~/pustoi.katalog
      ```
   3. после окончания работы с файлами в этом каталоге не забудьте его отмонтировать. как обычно для *fuse*:

      ```
      $ fusermount -u ~/pustoi.katalog
      ```
   4. посмотреть, что в данный момент куда примонтировано, можно, как обычно, программой `df`.
2. а работать с (уже ставшими локальными) файлами можно **любым** удобным редактором, хоть универсальным, хоть специализированным, хоть входящим в какую-нибудь интегрированную среду разработки.

---

чуть подробнее про использование curlftpfs: http://habrahabr.ru/post/85084/

Comment: спасибо большое уже разобрался как работать, просто первый день не понял сразу как и куда тыкать