# Не работает скрипт удаления старых файлов с ftp

Tags: bash, shell, ftp, резервное-копирование

Помогите разобраться, почему данный скрипт не работает.
Он раньше вроде как работал (я точно не помню) а сейчас не работает.

```
#!/bin/bash

PROGNAME=$(basename $0)

OUTFILE="/tmp/ftplist.$RANDOM.txt"
CMDFILE="/tmp/ftpcmd.$RANDOM.txt"
ndays=14

print_usage() {
    echo ""
    echo "$PROGNAME - Delete files older than N days from an FTP server"
    echo ""
    echo "Usage: $PROGNAME -s -u -p -f (-d)"
    echo ""
    echo "  -s  FTP Server name"
    echo "  -u  User Name"
    echo "  -p  Password"
    echo "  -f  Folder"
    echo "  -d  Number of Days (Default: $ndays)"
    echo "  -h  Show this page"
    echo ""
    echo "Usage: $PROGNAME -h"
    echo ""
    exit
}

# Parse parameters
options=':hs:u:p:f:d:'
while getopts $options flag
do
    case $flag in
        s)
            FTPSITE=$OPTARG
            ;;
        u)
            FTPUSER=$OPTARG
            ;;
        p)
            FTPPASS=$OPTARG
            ;;
        f)
            FTPDIR=$OPTARG
            ;;
        d)
            ndays=$OPTARG
            ;;
        h)
            print_usage
            ;;
        \?)
            echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
            exit 1
            ;;
        :)
            echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
done 

shift $(($OPTIND - 1))

if [[ -z "$FTPSITE" || -z "$FTPUSER" || -z "$FTPPASS" || -z "$FTPDIR" ]];
then
    echo "ERROR: Missing parameters"
    print_usage
fi


# work out our cutoff date
TDATE=`date --date="$ndays days ago" +%Y%m%d`

echo FTP Site: $FTPSITE
echo FTP User: $FTPUSER
echo FTP Password: $FTPPASS
echo FTP Folder: $FTPDIR
echo Removing files older than $TDATE

# get directory listing from remote source
ftp -i -n $FTPSITE <<EOMYF > /dev/null
user $FTPUSER $FTPPASS
binary
cd $FTPDIR
ls -l $OUTFILE
quit
EOMYF

if [ -f "$OUTFILE" ]
then

    # Load the listing file into an array
    lista=($(<$OUTFILE))

    # Create the FTP command file to delete the files
    echo "user $FTPUSER $FTPPASS" > $CMDFILE
    echo "binary" >> $CMDFILE
    echo "cd $FTPDIR"  >> $CMDFILE

    COUNT=0

    # loop over our files
    for ((FNO=0; FNO<${#lista[@]}; FNO+=9));do
        # month (element 5), day (element 6) and filename (element 8)
        FMM=${lista[`expr $FNO+5`]}
        FDD=${lista[`expr $FNO+6`]}
        FYY=${lista[`expr $FNO+7`]}

        if [[ $FYY == *\:* ]]
        then
            FDATE=`date -d "$FMM $FDD" +'%Y%m%d'`
        else
            FDATE=`date -d "$FMM $FDD $FYY" +'%Y%m%d'`
        fi

        # echo $FDATE
        # check the date stamp
        if [[ $FDATE -lt $TDATE ]];
        then
            echo "Deleting ${lista[`expr $FNO+8`]}"
            echo "delete ${lista[`expr $FNO+8`]}" >> $CMDFILE
            COUNT=$[$COUNT + 1]
        fi
    done
    echo "quit" >> $CMDFILE


    if [[ $COUNT -gt 0 ]];
    then
        cat $CMDFILE | tr -d "\r" > $CMDFILE
        ftp -i -n $FTPSITE < $CMDFILE > /dev/null
    else
        echo "Nothing to delete"
    fi

    rm -f $OUTFILE $CMDFILE
fi
```

[Original](https://gist.github.com/allanscullion/8484a7407ccfaf284a53)

---

Вот что я ещё заметил.
Файлы он находит верно, но не удаляет!

```
Removing files older than 20161026
Deleting 01.10.2016
Deleting 02.10.2016
Deleting 03.10.2016
Deleting 04.10.2016
Deleting 05.10.2016
Deleting 06.10.2016
Deleting 07.10.2016
Deleting 08.10.2016
Deleting 09.10.2016
Deleting 10.10.2016
Deleting 11.10.2016
Deleting 12.10.2016
Deleting 13.10.2016
Deleting 14.10.2016
Deleting 15.10.2016
Deleting 16.10.2016
Deleting 17.10.2016
Deleting 18.10.2016
Deleting 19.10.2016
Deleting 20.10.2016
Deleting 21.10.2016
Deleting 22.10.2016
Deleting 23.10.2016
Deleting 24.10.2016
Deleting 25.10.2016
Deleting 26.10.2016
```

Вот содержимое $OUTFILE

> drwxr-xr-x 2 user  backup 4096 Sep 30 21:03 01.10.2016 drwxr-xr-x 2 user   backup 4096 Oct 31 21:03 01.11.2016 drwxr-xr-x 2 user   backup 4096 Oct 1 21:03 02.10.2016 drwxr-xr-x 2 user    backup 4096 Nov 1 21:03 02.11.2016

Возможно это поможет в решении моей проблемы

Comment: А почему вы решили, что он не работает.

Comment: какие сложности. ведь можно просто [примонтировать каталог](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/480623/178576) и удалить: `$ find /путь/к/каталогу -type f -ctime +14 -delete`, не забыв после этого отмонтировать.

Comment: @0xdb Дело в том что он не удаляет файлы, хотя и определяет  "старые" верно.

Comment: Вам важно найти ошибку в этом скрипте, который неизвестно работал ли вообще, или старые файлы удалить? Если последние, то  alexander barakin вам уже предложил оптимальное решение.

Comment: Я не совсем понял вариант решения от товарища @alexander barakin
Что это мне даст?

Comment: @T1MOXA, **это** даст вам возможность сделать то, что написано в заголовке («удалить старые файлы с ftp»). разобраться с тем, работает ли приведённый вами скрипт вообще, и если не работает, то почему, **это** вам не поможет.

Comment: @T1MOXA У вас действительно  файлы с именами - к примеру 26.10.2016? Выложите содержимое `$OUTFILE`. Скрипт явно писали в прошлом веке, поэтому решение от товарища @alexander barakin поможет вам парой строчек кода и без головной боли решить проблему, т.е. удалить старые файлы.

Comment: @0xdb Вот содержимое $OUTFILE
`drwxr-xr-x   2 user   backup     4096 Sep 30 21:03 01.10.2016
drwxr-xr-x   2 user   backup     4096 Oct 31 21:03 01.11.2016
drwxr-xr-x   2 user   backup     4096 Oct  1 21:03 02.10.2016
drwxr-xr-x   2 user   backup     4096 Nov  1 21:03 02.11.2016`

Я кстати заметил что файл ftpcmd%RANDOM%.txt пуст, не уверен что так должно быть,

Comment: @T1MOXA Нет, пуст недолжен быть, должно быть  - delete  01.10.2016 ... и т.д..

Comment: @0xdb Возможно именно в этом дело.

Comment: Я уже начинаю подумывать над тем чтоб забить на этот скрипт и воспользоваться советом @alexander barakin.
Если использовать монтирование фтп, то это не как не отразится на свободном месте на машине?

Comment: @T1MOXA, нет, монтирование одной файловой системы никак не отражается на других файловых системах этого компьютера.

Comment: @alexander barakin У меня проблема с скриптом...
Он удалил все данные.
`curlftpfs ftp://$b_ftp_user:$b_ftp_pass@$b_ftp_host /mnt/temp_data`

Comment: `find /mnt/temp_data -mtime +40 -exec rm -rf {} \;`

Comment: @T1MOXA, если у вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки в правом верхнем углу страницы.

Comment: @alexander barakin А не слишком ли мелко для создания отдельного топика?

Comment: @T1MOXA А какой вопрос? Как написано, так и сработало - если  смонтированая папка не изменялась 40 дней, удалить её  со всем содержимым.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из мануала ftp -  `delete remote-file`. Скрипт удаляет только файлы,  а не папки.  Кроме того,  он не работает рекурсивно. В вашей конфигурации он никогда не работал,  или конфигурация была изменена потому, что скрипт получает путь,  где лежат только папки.

Самоё оптимальное решение - воспользоваться `find` как предложено в [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/589608/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81-ftp/589997#comment790586_589608):

[примонтировать каталог](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/480623/178576) и удалить:

```
$ find /mnt/mpoint -type f -ctime +14 -delete
```

Добавте `-fprint <лог-файл>`, если нужно протоколировать удалённые файлы,
или просто `-print`.

Comment: Спасибо, я так и сделаю.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Не забудте для начала без -delete проверить, что будет удално.