# Как в bash найти подстроку в строке и записать ее в переменную?

Tags: bash, консоль, ftp, terminal, sh

Пытаюсь написать скрипт который будет выкачивать дамп БД через lftp:

```
lftp -u user,password ftp.server.ru << EOF
ls
bye
EOF
```

Отработка вот что пишет:

```
drwxr-xr-x   1 8000027  8000027         0 Nov 28 14:48 2017-11-22                                  
drwxr-xr-x   1 8000027  8000027         0 Nov 28 14:48 2017-11-23
drwxr-xr-x   1 8000027  8000027         0 Nov 28 14:48 2017-11-24
drwxr-xr-x   1 8000027  8000027         0 Nov 28 14:48 2017-11-25
drwxr-xr-x   1 8000027  8000027         0 Nov 28 14:48 2017-11-26
drwxr-xr-x   1 8000027  8000027         0 Nov 28 14:48 2017-11-27
drwxr-xr-x   1 8000027  8000027         0 Nov 28 14:48 2017-11-28
```

Нужно записать в переменную название последний папки: 2017-11-28.

Сразу хочу предупредить что я не по ssh подключаюсь
ls ключи не принимает (это lftp убого эмулируется как баш и дает некоторые его возможности, но про эмуляцию могу ошибаться) и выводит только в таком виде в котором я написал, тупо названия файлов вывести штатным способом нельзя!
Нужно полюбому использовать grep и\или sed (они в lftp есть)

---

ls | tail -n 1
Выводит
drwxr-xr-x   1 8000027  8000027         0 Nov 28 16:24 2017-11-28

ls ключи никакие не принимает! 
Ругается на них, мол типа нет такого файла -la (при ls -la)
Нужно только передачей потока в какую нибудь grep или sed или пр.

Comment: вряд ли стоит так извращаться. проще ведь будет работать с локальным каталогом/файлом, [выполнив монтирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/480623/178576).

Comment: Про скачивание архива .tgz оформите отдельным вопросом, иначе не соответствует описание вопроса заголовку и является слишком общим.

Comment: Проще не будет. Мне нужно что бы по запуске команды sudo bash ./backup.sh Скачивался с сервера архив ко мне на комп. Архив находится в последней папке. (здесь много в этой папке архивов, мне нужен последний)

Comment: @Lancer, гарантирую: будет проще. особенно если без всяких `sudo bash`. алогритм: 1. примонтировать. 2. сделать нужные манипуляции с локально-видимым каталогом. 3. отмонтировать. 4. польза.

Comment: а как это сделать? Скинь ссылку пжлст на доку

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Действительно это оказалось намного проще! Даже и не знал что линукс так могёт (только две недели на нем сижу). С каждым днем афигеваю с его(линукса) простоты и одновременно мощи! Спасибо за помощь, вопрос закрыт!

Answer (score 2):

На примере вывода содержимого из /tmp

```
AB=`ls -laht /tmp/ | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $9}'`; echo "Значение переменной AB: $AB"

Значение переменной AB: ..
```

Comment: AB=`ls -laht /tmp/ | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $9}'`; echo "Значение переменной AB: $AB"

Неизвестная команда `AB=`ls'.
Значение переменной AB: $AB

Comment: это же совсем не *bash*!

Comment: @alexanderbarakin метки вопроса говорят об обратном.

Comment: @edem, вот это, например, *bash*: `ls -laht /tmp/ | while read a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9; do echo "значение переменной: $a9"; done`, а то, что вы привели, к программе bash вообще никаким боком. а среди меток как раз и наблюдается слово *bash* (а ещё *sh*, *console* и *terminal*!). и ни слова ни о каких awk/tail

Comment: Ну в терминале фтп сервера пишу. Тогда на каком языке там пишется. Сервак на линуксе, я и подумал на баш надо писать, тем более многие команды для баш подходят (я бы даже сказал все)

Comment: ls | tail -n 1
drwxr-xr-x   1 8000027  8000027         0 Nov 28 16:24 2017-11-28